# Json Parser Data

Tags: android, json

I have create JSONPARSE data for my android apps. I using LogCat able to view Json respond using Log.d("id", id ) but it shown error when i want to set the textview value into id. Please help, Thanks. Below is the Code that i use for java and php

Below is my code.

Log cat :
[image]

```
MainActivity.Java



   private static String url_Retrieve =       "http://hospital.leeyengyang.com/android_connect/Retrieve.php";
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL

                JSONObject json2 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_Retrieve, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse 
                Log.d("All Products: ", json2.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success2 = json2.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success2 == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        JSONArray Retrieve = json2.getJSONArray("tracking");

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < Retrieve.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = Retrieve.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString("Data");
                            String name = c.getString("Username");


                            Log.d("id", id);
                            Log.d("name", name);    
                            // creating new HashMap


                            txtUpdate.setText(id);
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                        }
                    } else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                Bluetooth.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 



Retrive.php
  <?php
// Locate WP Location
$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

include ($location . '/wp-config.php');
include ($location . '/wp-load.php');
include ($location . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
    $date =  date("Y-m-d");
$sql="SELECT Data,Username FROM tracking Where Username='jin' AND Date= '".$date."'";

// Initial Add data to HM
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["tracking"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $tracking = array();
    $tracking["Data"] = $row["Data"];
    $tracking["Username"] = $row["Username"];



    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["tracking"], $tracking);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} 

else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>

JsonParser.Java

package com.example.Leeyengyang;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your error has something to do with AsyncTask.

Comment: you cant update UI in doInBackground() ie.  `txtUpdate.setText(id);` write this in onPostExecute or in doInBackground using runOnUiThread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetText like that.
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {

         txtUpdate.setText(id); 
        }
    });
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

For setting int value into TextView use

```
txtUpdate.setText(""+id);
// OR
txtUpdate.setText(Integer.toString(id));
```

basically you need to convert int value to String. It does not set int value directly to TextView.

Make sure that you are updaing UI from Main Thread only.

Hope this helps !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change your UI from outside of the UI thread (for example `doInBackground()` method of `AsyncTask`).

Although - you still can do this update in onPostExecute, that is called after background work has been done and is runningo on the main (UI) thread.

Also, consider to use one of libraries that can simplify whole process like Jake Wharton's Retrofit: http://square.github.io/retrofit/